# BizTalk SendPort InboundBodyPathExpression XPath

Tags: xpath, biztalk, biztalk-2010

The following is a real message being received from a 3rd party once I've called their web service:

```
<TransferRequest>
<SecurityHeader>
<...Removed, but not bothered by this/>
</SecurityHeader>
<TransferReq xmlns="'http://www.removedforthepostonstackoverflow">
.....
```

In my BizTalk map, I need the information without the given security header (so using TransferReq as root) - I've tried generating an XSD that includes the header but I cant do that - due to the default namespace being named below the root.

I've tried amending the BizTalk InboundBodyPathExpression so it uses XPath to find my relevant node to use as its root node, as per microsofts documentation here: [Specifying the Message Body for the WCF Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226478.aspx)

This is my xpath:

```
/*[local-name()='TransferRequest']/*[local-name()='TransferReq' and namespace()='http://www.removedforthepostonstackoverflow']
```

Above is what is returned by the 3rd party

I get this however, being thrown:

> Endpoint handler communication exception.  An error occurred while processing the messageError Description: System.InvalidOperationException: Inbound body path expression "/*[local-name()='TransferRequest']/*[local-name()='TransferReq' and namespace()='http://www.removedforthepostonstackoverflow']" is invalid.

Can someone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is obvious**:

There is no XPath function `namespace()` -- you need to use the standard XPath function:

`namespace-uri()`

Comment: I looked at it over and over so many times and missed such an obvious thing - thank you... bounty coming when it lets me!